# Common theme for all Buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

i want to make a common theme for all my buttons in all activities across the whole applications. i want to put just 2 images for Focus and Default...i want to do all in xml how can i do this ??

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_focused" />

        <item
            android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed_focused" />

        <item
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />

        <item android:color="#ffffff" />

    </selector>
```

Comment: it need to be call in every button's background..how do i call it in Manifest to make it common, ??
my App has a lot of pages, its a hectic job to edit all backgrouds

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use theming for your buttons. Read this: [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: it applies to whole activity like activity background also changed.. but i just want to change Button's background. how to apply theme for just Buttons.. instead of calling the theme in every button background

Comment: Yes you can define Theme for that. Include that theme inside the <application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style for your button, then create a style (which is a theme) with a parent such as

```
parent="android:Theme.something"
```

with the value

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/my_button_style</item>
```

Then in the manifest, there is a `theme` attribute both in the application and the activity element.

Comment: i have tried its not working for me, it changes the background of activity :(